# Reverse engineering: How to generate SOAP Request XML in the backend?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws, java-ee-7

I have the following classes:

**WS Interface:**

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;

@Remote
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
@WebService(name = "MathService", targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/")
public interface MathServiceWS {

    @WebResult(name = "result", targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "addRequest", className = "AddRequest", targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/")
    @WebMethod(action = "http://mypackage.com/add", operationName = "add")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "addResponse", className = "AddResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/")
    Long add(@WebParam(name = "add", targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/") AddBean add);
}
```

**WS Implementation:**

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Stateless(mappedName = "MathService")
@WebService(serviceName = "MathService", endpointInterface = "com.mypackage.MathServiceWS", portName = "MathServicePort", targetNamespace = "http://mypackage.com/")
public class MathService implements MathServiceWS {

    @Override
    public Long add(AddBean add) {
        Long first = new Long(add.getFirst().intValue());
        Long second = new Long(add.getSecond().intValue());
        return Long.valueOf(Math.addExact(first.longValue(), second.longValue()));
    }
}
```

**The bean:**

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "Add",
    namespace = "http://mypackage.com/",
    propOrder = {
        "first",
        "second"
    }
)
public class AddBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7727938355039425419L;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Integer first;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Integer second;

    public AddBean() {

    }

    public Integer getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(Integer first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public Integer getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(Integer second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

After deploying this WS, when I'm adding the WSDL in SoapUI, the add method request is as follows after giving the user input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:myp="http://mypackage.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <myp:addRequest>
         <myp:add>
            <first>1</first>
            <second>2</second>
         </myp:add>
      </myp:addRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I want to have the above SOAP request XML in my `com.mypackage.MathService.add(AddBean)` method with the given user input.

- Using JAXB on `com.mypackage.AddBean` only generates partial request
- **The WebService Handlers is not useful to fulfill my requirement**

Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: I assume your webservice works well, just don't know how to connect it. Would you like to call it from the same JVM or a different one? In the first case, you should be able to inject it with @EJB and call it as a java bean, in the last case, you should generate a webservice client and use it to connect to the remote service.

Comment: what exactly means "a partial request".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an custom SOAPHandler object and can read the request payload and set it to SOAPMessageContext via custom property. Make sure you set the scope as application.

In your service class, inject the `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext` using `@javax.annotation.Resource` and access payload set via your custom property.

For example:

1. Create Handler and register it.

```
public class PopulateSOAPMessagePayloadHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    public static final String SOAP_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD = "__soap_message_payload";

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (!outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            // for incoming:
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            try {
                smc.getMessage().writeTo(bout);
                String payload = bout.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

                smc.put(SOAP_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD, payload);  //Set payload
                smc.setScope(SOAP_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD, MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);  //make it application scope

            } catch (SOAPException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // handle exception if needed
                throw new WebServiceException(e);
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
 // Other method (no-op) omitted 
}
```

2. Get the payload

```
public class MathService implements MathServiceWS {
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    @Override
    public Long add(AddBean add) {
        String payload = (String) context.getMessageContext().get(SOAP_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD);

        Long first = new Long(add.getFirst().intValue());
        Long second = new Long(add.getSecond().intValue());
        return Long.valueOf(Math.addExact(first.longValue(), second.longValue()));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I think your solution could solve the issue. If I need to use this SOAPHandler for multiple WS and methods, I need to extract the service name and operation name within the handler and create the name of the payload accordingly. I'm going to give it a try. Thank you again for the pointer. But what about the concurrent access?

Comment: The context is specific to current on-going request. So you don't need to worry about concurrency. Also I don't you need to create separate payload name..

Answer (score 0):

You can get full control of the document easily. First lets setup the bean:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="addRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) //Probably you don't need this line. it is by default field accessible. 
public class AddBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7727938355039425419L;

@XmlElement(name="first",required = true) //you don't need name attribute as field is already exactly the same as soap element
private Integer first;

@XmlElement(name="second",required = true) //you don't need name attribute as field is already exactly the same as soap element
private Integer second;

public AddBean() { }
//Getters and Setters
}
```

Now, I think this is the part you are looking for. To add custom namespace declarations and set prefix etc. If you are using `org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport.getWebServiceTemplate` to make SOAP request, then you can do the following:

```
public class WSCastorClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

public CustomResponseObject callWebService(Addbean add) {
WebServiceTemplate wst = getWebServiceTemplate();
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
wst.setMarshaller(marshaller);
wst.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
wst.afterPropertiesSet();
CustomResponseObject response = (CustomResponseObject) 
wst.marshallSendAndReceive(add, new 
WebServiceMessageCallback() {

    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) { 
        SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
        SOAPMesage soapMEssage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader head = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
        //Now you have full control of the soap header, body, envelope. You can add any namespace declaration, prefix, add header element, etc. You can add remove whatever you want. 
        soapEnvelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(soapEnvelope.getPrefix()); //clear whatever namespace is there
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("myp", "http://mypackage.com/");
        soapEnvelope.setPrefix("soapenv");
        soapHeader.setPrefix("soapenv");
        soapBody.setPrefix("soapenv");

        Document doc = saajSoapMessage.getDocument();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        Transformer transformer  = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
    }       
    });
return response;
}
//close off other brackets if I forgot any.
```

Comment: Thank you. 1. I cannot really add `@XmlRootElement(name="addRequest")` in `AddBean`. There are many beans which are not at all have `@XmlRootElement`. 2 I am not using springframework.ws.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: your second code block has low readability and it makes it hard for reusing it in the future. can you make it more readable so it would have a better impact on other developers? here is something you can do: add some blank lines and separate different parts of your code and make your comments more readable. thank you :)

Comment: My brother @MohammadHosseinShojaeinia, I used somewhat similar code in my application. No wonder this code was thrown out of the application. lmao